# Let $d_1$ and $d_2$ be two equivalent metrics. If $A$ is an open subset of $(X,d_1)$ is $A$ an open subset of $(X,d_2)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Let $d_1$ and $d_2$ be two equivalent metrics. If $A$ is an open subset of $(X,d_1)$, is $A$ an open subset of $(X,d_2)$?

---

Well, I have that if two metrics are equivalent then every sequence in $(X,d_1)$ is convergent in $(X,d_2)$. Now, let $\{a_{n}\}$ be an arbitrary sequence that converges to $x_0\in A^c \subset X$ under $d_1$, with $x_0$ a limit point (or accumulation point). Then, the sequence converges by definition of equivalent metrics in $(X,d_2)$. Now, we know that $\{a_{n}\}$ converges to some point $x_1$ in $(X,d_2)$ but not necessarily $x_0$ = $x_1$ (I can prove that). So then, it can be that in $A^c \subset X$ under $d_2$ does not contain every accumulation point  (I’m saying that it can be $x_1 \not\in A^c$). Then $A^c$ isn’t a closed set and we cannot prove anything. Or until now I can’t find a way to prove that $x_1\in A^c$.

Any suggestions? Am I right?

---

A time ago I proved in some homework that if some metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent then we can bound each other, something like:

$$\exists C : d_1 \leq C d_2 \land \exists K : d_2 \leq K d_1$$

But I can’t prove it to the other side, it may help

Comment: Your "definition" of metric equivalence is not standard, see wikipedia [Equivalence of metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A \subseteq X$ be open with respect to $d_1$. Because $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent, there exists $C_1,C_2 > 0$ such that
$$
 C_1 d_1(x,y) \leq d_2(x,y) \leq C_2d_1(x,y)
$$
for all $x,y \in X$.  Let now $x \in A$ be given. Since $A$ is open with respect to $d_1$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that
$$
B(x,\epsilon; d_1) \subseteq A.
$$
Here, $B(x,\epsilon; d_1)$ denotes the open ball (with respect to $d_1$)
$$
\left\{ y \in X : d_1(x,y) < \epsilon \right\}.
$$
Now, consider the open ball (with respect to $d_2$):
$$
B := B\left( x, {C_1}{\epsilon}; d_2\right).
$$
We claim that $B \subseteq B(x,\epsilon; d_1) \subseteq A$ which would complete the proof. Indeed, if $y \in B$ then 
\begin{align*}
d_1(x,y)\leq \frac{d_2(x,y)}{C_1} < \frac{C_1\epsilon}{C_1} = \epsilon.
\end{align*}
Hence, $y \in B(x,\epsilon;d_1) \subseteq A$. By symmetry, you can then conclude that open subsets of $(X,d_2)$ are open in $(X,d_1)$ as well. This means that equivalent metrics induce the same topology on $X$.

---

**Edit**: Let's instead only assume that $d_1$ and $d_2$ satisfy the following property:

> A sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x \in X$ with respect to $d_1$ if and only if it converges to $x$ with respect to $d_2$.

If $A$ is open with respect to $d_1$, then it will still be open with respect to $d_2$. To verify this, it would be enough to check that $A^\complement$ is closed with respect to $d_2$. To this end, let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $A^\complement$ converging to $x \in X$ with respect to $d_2$. Then, we have $x_n \to x$ in $(X,d_1)$ by assumption. Since $A^\complement$ is closed in $(X,d_1)$, we get that $x \in A^\complement$. This ensures that $A^\complement$ is closed in $(X,d_2)$, and so $A$ is open in this same space.

Comment: Any hint to prove that because d1 and d2 are equivalent there exists C1 and C2 such that...? I thaugh in that but I can only prove it to the other side, I mean if there exists some C1 and C2 such that... then d1 and d2 are equivalent. Sorry for the inconveniences, I edited the question adding that part but it didn’t save it or something

Comment: Your definition of equivalence does not necessarily imply this criterion. In fact, I think you have the wrong definition of equivalence. Typically, one would either assume that such $C_1, C_2 > 0$ exist. Or, more generally, that a sequence converges to $x$ in $(X,d_1)$ if and only if it also converges to $x$ with respect to $(X,d_2)$. See my edit for a proof using this more general definition.